# Getting "speechSynthesis" is not defined in jjs(Java JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, speech-synthesis, jjs

I am attempting to access the **SpeechSynthesis interface for speech service** with the help of the **Nashorn** engine in **java**. Is it possible to import or create a similar  SpeechSynthesis interface to the Nashorn engine Or any other javascript engine with this interface?

Javascript statement to speak "Hello world!"

```
speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello world!"))
```

In jjs(Java Javascript) tool:

```
jjs> speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello world!"));
<shell>:1 ReferenceError: "speechSynthesis" is not defined
jjs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is: **No, it's not possible** to synthesize speech with Nashorn for Java.

The **real issue** (of not working) is because the Speech Synthesis API uses `window.` a property which is only available from a browser display. See basic code from: [SpeechSynthesisUtterance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance)

```
var mySynth = window.speechSynthesis; //window must exist for code to work
```

**(1)**

> `ReferenceError: "speechSynthesis" is not defined`

A more correct way to write your original code would be to declare a variable first:

```
jjs> var mySynth = speechSynthesis;
jjs> mySynth.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello world!"));
```

This would cancel the Reference Error: `"speechSynthesis" is not defined` because your original code is referencing an undefined variable called `"speechSynthesis"`.

**(2)**

> *"Is it possible to import or create a similar `SpeechSynthesis` interface to the Nashorn engine Or any other javascript engine with this interface?"*

You cannot use the SpeechSynthesis API in a command-line tool (*eg:* [using JJS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/jjs.html)). It needs a browser.

The alternative is to just do the Text-To-Speech part within Java itself.
You will need a third-part free TTS tool to plug into the Java Speech API.

[Basic tutorial on using Java with OpenTTS (third-party)](https://www.javatpoint.com/processing-speech-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

> While Oracle Nashorn runs ECMA-compliant JavaScript, it is important to note that objects normally accessible in a web browser are not available, for example, console, window, and so on.

[source](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-nashorn.html)

This also includes the [SpeechSynthesis API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis), which is a Web Browser feature and not part of core JavaScript/[ECMA-262](https://262.ecma-international.org/).